# how to use an static var from child class in its parent class with an static method

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, static, static-binding

I want to get the value of the static var that was redeclared in the subclass :

```
    class A {

        private static $echo_var = 'PARENT_ECHO' ;

        public static function e() {
            return '$echo_var = ' . self::$echo_var ;
        }
    }

    class B extends A {

        private static $echo_var = 'CHILD_ECHO';
    }

    echo B::e();
```

I want to get CHILD_ECHO.

thanks,
Mottenmann

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the **static** keyword when accesing it:

```
return '$echo_var = ' . static::$echo_var ;
```

It's called [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php). But it won't work on private members. You'll have to make it public or protected. Private properties are accessible only in the class in which they are defined.

Comment: wonderfull ! Thank you very much i knew about late static binding but never really understood how to use the static:: . But its so simple :)

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 errors:

- `ECHO` is a reserved name.
- Use `protected` instead of `private`
- Use `static` instead of `self`

```php
class A
{

    protected static $echo_var = 'PARENT_ECHO' ;

    public static function output()
    {
        return '$echo_var = ' . static::$echo_var ;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    protected static $echo_var = 'CHILD_ECHO';
}

echo B::output();
```

Comment: why its looks like its under 3ed list item ? still strange